# Google adwords api slow performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, caching, google-ads-api

Has anyone noticed a
Google adwords API very slow time to time? I'm thinking of caching data on cloudfront based on query string in my api to reduce the load to the Google api.

How can we improve performance of intefrated results of Google adwords API?

Comment: If you're talking about the new Google Ads API, that one is indeed significantly slower than the old Google Adwords API.

Answer (score 1):

If an endpoint returns the same results every time, you can use **AWS CloudFront** to cache the contents for a fixed time before it reaches the origin.

You can create origin and choose your desired cache settings.

If you want your cache timing to be dynamic, you can cache based on query string parameters.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/QueryStringParameters.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: the data is very variable time to time so probably not cacheable (I mean not many duplicates) is there a better way?

Comment: You can configure the cacheable time in cloudfront. If you want an intermediate caching layer, you can introduce a lambda with DynamoDB table that can return the last successful result.